# How to search in a nested array inside lookup pipeline MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Appointment sample data

```
{
        "doctorId": "623f484709fb21a7760ce187",
        "userId": "6223370153c8126cd85884ce",
        "forUser": {
            "whom": "other",
            "id": "626249c4b666dc59628502f2"
        },
        "appointmentType": "walkin",
        "dates": {
            "createdAt": "2022-04-30T08:06:30.066Z",
            "forDateAndShift": {
                "date": "2022-05-02T00:00:00.000Z",
                "shift": "623f484709fb21a7760ce188"
            }
        },
        "status": "confirmed",
        "_id": "626cee063558d4a281fcccdb",
    }
```

Doctor Sample Data

```
"name": "Someone",
    "profile": {
        "qualification": "MBBS",
        "speciality": "Cardiologist",
        "experience": 5
    },
    "timeSlots": [
        {
            "day": "3",
            "shifts": [
                {
                     _id:"623f484709fb21a7760ce188"
                    "maximumAllowedAppointments": 30,
                    "startTime": {
                        "hours": "9",
                        "minutes": "0"
                    },
                    "endTime": {
                        "hours": "12",
                        "minutes": "0"
                    }
                },
            ]
        },
```

Want to get doctor shift timing that matches the appointment shift id  tried that using the pipeline and let inside lookup and that did not give any output except for an empty array.
Query tried to achieve the same

```
appointment.aggregate([
  { $match: { userId: user._id } },
  { $sort: { "dates.forDateAndShift.date": 1 } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "doctors",
      localField: "doctorId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      let: { shiftId: "$dates.forDateAndShift.shift" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { "timeSlots.shifts": { $elemMatch: { _id: "$$shiftId" } } } }
      ],
      as: "doctor"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$doctor" },
  {
    $project: {
      status: 1,
      forUser: 1,
      dates: 1,
      serialNumber: 1,
      "doctor.name": 1,
      appointmentType: 1,
      "doctor.profile": 1
    }
  },
  { $group: { _id: "$status", appointments: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
  { $project: { _id: 0, status: "$_id", appointments: "$appointments" } }
])
```

I am writing this part of this question in order to avoid the warning of all code from stack overflow thus request you to kindly ignore this section

Comment: Please provide some ample data

Comment: [This](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kkdvZvPPpA0) is an example from another answer. You provide some sample data, So we can use it to show example for the query you need. It also allows you to define the expected outcome you want from such data.

Comment: We need your data before the lookup. It should look like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/kswMYuGf-QN . Please fix this to match your data before the lookup

Comment: updated the same in the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get the right shift in the `doctor` is:

```
db.appointment.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {userId: "6223370153c8126cd85884ce"}
  },
  {
    $sort: {"dates.forDateAndShift.date": 1}
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "doctors",
      let: {
        shiftId: "$dates.forDateAndShift.shift",
        doctorId: "$doctorId"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {$expr: {$eq: ["$_id", "$$doctorId"]}}
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$timeSlots"
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            shifts: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$timeSlots.shifts",
                as: "item",
                cond: {$eq: ["$$item._id", "$$shiftId"]}
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$addFields": {"shiftsCount": {$size: "$shifts"}}
        },
        {
          $match: {shiftsCount: {$gt: 0}}
        },
        {
          $unset: "shiftsCount"
        }
      ],
      as: "doctor"
    }
  },
 // TODO: continue your query
])
```

You can see how it work on this [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/p5fFiM-n5t5).

If the shift_id is unique, you can continue the `$lookup` pipeline with:

```
{$project: {shifts: {$arrayElemAt: ["$shifts", 0]}}}
```

Comment: the last match in pipeline is not working for me its giving an empty list

Comment: Did it work on the playground example?

Comment: yes it did work there

Comment: If it works on the playground but not on your actual data, you need to find the difference between them. Common problems are mongodb version and _id string/objectId format

Comment: What is your mongodb version?

Comment: the version is 4.4.1

Comment: but the last match doesn't contain any such thing like objectId its just matching with the size of the array and without using that its working fine its just that empty arrays are also displayed

Comment: sounds like this problem should be easy to solve. One way is to debug it, for example start with projecting `{$size: "$shifts"}`, to see if it is zero and one. Another option is to try to reproduce the problem on the playground and share it.

Comment: maybe you use `$gte` instead of `$gt`

Comment: doesn't help still the same output empty doctor list

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem on the playground and share it

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ci2YmUrzfYW

Comment: Here it works. The empty [] is for a case of no match at all. It has nothing to do with the last step of the $lookup

Comment: You are searching for "doctorId": ObjectId("623f484709fb21a7760ce189"), but there is no such thing in the doctors collection

Comment: If it works for you please accept it, so it will be easier for others to find it.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/BwlojAW-Qgn I have made the doctor id same still it gives an empty list

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/p5fFiM-n5t5

Comment: thanks a lot :) for your time and patience I really appreciate it  just one question is this approach optimized enough to deploy on a production grade API

Comment: The `$lookup` part after the `$match` part are fine, but I don't understand the `$sort` part. Consider if you need it. If you do need it. it is ok after the `$match`